# Routing in Express.js - dynamic number of parameters

Tags: node.js, express

I've a concept for create routing with multiple parameters when numbers of it are dynamic, for example:

```
/v2/ModuleName/Method/Method2/
```

In Express I want parse it as: `Modules.v2.ModuleName.Method.Method2()`. When will be just one method, this should be of course `Modules.v2.ModuleName.Method()`. It's possible to do that?

Comment: It is possible. But be careful! Users may hack your website. You can split `/v2/name/method` to `['v2','name','method']` then `Modules['v2']['name']['method']();`

Comment: But this is works only when i define 3 parameters, how about for eg. just 2 parameters? I'm thinking about app.get("*"), and split URL, but how about call function? `eval()` is evil...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can split pathname then lookup the method from your `Modules` object like this:

```
// fields = ['v2', 'ModuleName', 'Method', 'Method2']

var method = Modules;
fields.forEach(function (field) {
    method = method[field];
})

// call method
console.log(method());
```

Full code:

```
var express = require('express'), url = require('url');
var app = express();

Modules = {
    method: function () { return 'I am root'},
    v2: {
        method: function () { return 'I am v2';}
    }
};

app.get('/callmethod/*', function (req, res) {
    var path = url.parse(req.url).pathname;

    // split and remove empty element;
    path = path.split('/').filter(function (e) {
        return e.length > 0;
    });

    // remove the first component 'callmethod'
    path = path.slice(1);

    // lookup method in Modules:
    var method = Modules;
    path.forEach(function (field) {
        method = method[field];
    })

    console.log(method());
    res.send(method());

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Test on browser:

http://example.com:3000/callmethod/method

"I am root"

http://example.com:3000/callmethod/v2/method

"I am v2"

PS: *you can improve this app to support pass params to a method via url:
 http://example.com:3000/callmethod/v2/method?param1=hello&param2=word*